# Polynomial equations over $\mathbb{Z}_m$ where m is not a power of a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

When I have a polynomial equation over $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $m=p_1^{l_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_k^{l_k} $
First for every $\,p_i^{l_i}\,$ I solve using Hensel Lifting $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,(mod\,p_i^{l_i})$
For example, results I get look like: 
 
$\begin{array}{l}
 f(x)=x^2+5x+24\equiv 0\,(mod\,36)\\
 x \equiv 0,3 \,(mod\, 2^2)\\
 x \equiv 6,7 \,(mod\, 3^2)
\end{array}$

Now what? Do I use Chinese Remainder Theorem? For which of the results? (0,6) and (3,7) separately?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You suggest using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and this seems to be a good idea. Have you already tried this to see what happens? There are four possible combinations out there, which can be `lifted' to possible solutions mod 36. Just plug them into your $f$ and see what happens - they should all be solutions to $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem only for 0 and 3 mod 2^2 makes non sense and so does 6 and 7 mod 3^2. I feel confused how am I supposed to "combine" these.

Comment: No, but you can combine each of the results mod 4 with each of the results mod 9, as @Anderas Caranti explicitly states below. You can't use the chinese remainder theorem on different numbers mod 4, since 4 and 4 are not relatively prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, solve the four systems of congruences
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}x \equiv 0 \pmod{4}\\x \equiv 6\pmod{9}\end{cases}
\quad
\begin{cases}x \equiv 0 \pmod{4}\\x \equiv 7\pmod{9}\end{cases}
\quad
\begin{cases}x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}\\x \equiv 6\pmod{9}\end{cases}
\quad
\begin{cases}x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}\\x \equiv 7\pmod{9}\end{cases}
\end{equation}